# Error: bot/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node: invalid ELF header. Как исправить?

Tags: node.js, debian, virtual-hosts

Пользуюсь хостингом RuVDS, установлены Debian 11, Node.JS v.16.16.0. При запуске программы выдает данную ошибку. Как ее исправить?

````
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: bot/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node: invalid ELF header
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1189:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hyperdist_blitzstats/bot/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}```
````

Comment: Как вы установили на хостинге этот самый canvas?

Comment: npm i canvas@2.11.2

Comment: И делали вы это на своем компьютере?

Comment: нет, я на хостинг загружал